# Преобразование money к numeric PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица:

```
\d money
                              Таблица "public.money"
Столбец  |           Тип            |                    Модификаторы                    

----------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
id       | integer                  | NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('money_id_seq'::regclass)
type     | smallint                 | 
count    | money                    | 
comment  | text                     | 
time     | timestamp with time zone | NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
username | integer                  | NOT NULL

Индексы:
    "money_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Ограничения-проверки:
    "money_count_check" CHECK (count > 0::money)
Ограничения внешнего ключа:
    "money_type_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES types(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "money_username_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(id)
```

Хочу сделать в колонке **count** поменять тип данных с *money* на *numeric*.

Делаю запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE money ALTER COLUMN count SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC(2) USING count::money::numeric;
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
ОШИБКА:  оператор не существует: numeric > money
ПОДСКАЗКА:  Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.
```

Как правильно преобразовать тип колонки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательнее на текст ошибки:

> ОШИБКА:  оператор не существует: numeric > money

Почему ищется оператор сравнения?

> "money_count_check" CHECK (count > 0::money)

А вот почему, у вас добавлено ограничение на данные.

Вам необходимо удалить это ограничение и добавить новое после смены типа данных

```
begin;
alter table money drop constraint money_count_check;
alter table money alter column count set data type numeric;
alter table money add constraint money_count_check check (count > 0::numeric);
commit;
```

Обратите внимание, такие действия на большой таблице могут выполняться долго и заблокируют все пишущие операции.

И что более важно - вы действительно хотели изменить тип данных на `numeric(2)`? Т.е. хранить значения в диапазоне от -99 до 99 без дробной части? (плюс check отрезающий отрицательные значения) Для такого диапазона используйте `smallint` - это простой тип данных в отличии от numeric и занимает меньше места. (2 байта вместо, если не ошибаюсь, 16 для numeric(2))

Comment: Да, действительно... совсем забыл про ограничение! Все таки смотреть  и видеть - это разные вещи. А про numeric я перепутал параметры масштаб и точность местами. Мне нужно хранить число с 2 десятичными знаками. Лучше будут сделать так numeric(10,2), например. А про размер хранения, так сказано, что значение переменно. Спасибо за ответ! Вы сделали моё утро :)